# IF+AND function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, if

I have to check if the value in C2 is in the column F, IF it is AND the last digit of C2 is "1", I want it to return as "Incorrect Variant" or blank.

How do I write the correct formula?

So if you see in the picture, I have to check if the Material number is in the Column "new version" (which is in another tab), IF it is and the market is ordering the wrong version, I need it to say "Incorrect Variant", if not blank. Some material number won't be in the New Version list, and the order is scattered.

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp2Xd.png)

Comment: [this may be useful](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=Excel+IF+AND+formula+example)

Comment: `=IF(AND(`this`;`that`);`It was true`;`it was false`)`

Comment: But how do you put into the formula "if C2 is anywhere in column F AND the last digit do not match" ?

Comment: Check `VLOOKUP()`, it will find it, if it exists, then add/use `IFERROR()` to handle the "not found" gracefully.

Comment: As I do not know how your data looks, it is impossible to write something that applies to your data.

Comment: thank you, I put a picture to explain better the situation if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first part of your formula test for the 1. That way, only (you know... "maybe" depending upon the data characteristics) only 10% of the values have to be tested for existing in column F. Not essential, but it seems likely to speed up calculations, plus it lets you use a nested `IF()` structure for you formula which your experience may include, so it may be easier for you:

```
=IF(RIGHT(C1,1)<>1,"You didn't specify what should happen for this.",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,F:F,1,FALSE),"You didn't specify what should happen for this.","Incorrect Variant"))
```

Hmm... looks all awkward, eh?

Clearer way?

```
=IF(AND(RIGHT(C2,1)=1,NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,F:F,1,FALSE)))),"Incorrect Variant","You didn't specify what should happen for this.")
```

So do it the first way and your spreadsheet will probably be faster, though how much and whether that matters are beyond telling here.

Do it the second way and it's a little more straightforward to read and understand, I think.

(Of course, for "You didn't specify what should happen for this." in either, use whatever you want to have happen for those values that lead to failure to match your problem's given criteria.)

Answer (score 0):

please check if following formula is helpful to you.

```
=IF(RIGHT(C2,1)="1",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,F:F,1,FALSE)),"","Incorrect Variant"),"Others")
```

[image]